# "SET LOCAL can only be used in transaction blocks" warning in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, psql, table-lock, lock-timeout

When setting [lock_timeout](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-LOCK-TIMEOUT) 10 seconds locally on psql as shown below:

```
SET LOCAL lock_timeout = 10000;
```

I got the warning below on psql:

> WARNING: SET LOCAL can only be used in transaction blocks

Then, `SET LOCAL lock_timeout = 10000;` doesn't apply to the following transaction at all so `lock table person;` waits to lock the table forever without timeout after 10 seconds as shown below:

```
postgres=# SET LOCAL lock_timeout = 10000;
WARNING:  SET LOCAL can only be used in transaction blocks
SET
postgres=# BEGIN;
BEGIN
postgres=*# LOCK TABLE person; # Waits to lock the table forever
```

So, how can I solve the warning then apply `SET LOCAL lock_timeout = 10000;` to the following transaction?

Answer (score 3):

As the warning below says:

> WARNING: SET LOCAL can only be used in transaction blocks

You need to use `SET LOCAL` in transaction after running `BEGIN` then it works properly as shown below:

```
postgres=# BEGIN;
BEGIN
postgres=*# SET LOCAL lock_timeout = 10000;
SET
postgres=*# LOCK TABLE person; # Waits to lock the table for 10 seconds
ERROR:  canceling statement due to lock timeout # Cancelled after 10 seconds
postgres=!#
```